# 啰 vs. 囉 in Old Texts

Tags: simplified-characters, topolect, traditional-characters

啰 seems to be the simplified version of 囉 these days, but....these are two examples from 《四川方言词典》circa '87 that I found:

[image]

> **要飞啰**

[image]

> 我是乌梢蛇打店——长客**囉**!

Most the entries I've seen in these 八零后 books have all been written *囉* and I just assumed it was a later simplification but obviously *啰* as a character also existed at the same time!

- What's The Difference Between 啰 And 囉 In Old(er) Texts?

...seems like there is no difference between the two nowadays...

edit:

[image: ok]

> “～囉”

[image: hi]

> 拐啰

and the most crazy of them all:

[image: ha]

at the top:

> 涮啰

in the def:

> 涮囉

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a failure of editing. 啰 is actually discussed in the 1986 [Jianhuazi zong biao](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh/%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%97%E6%80%BB%E8%A1%A8). According to the 1986 zong biao, 罗 was included in the first list of simplified characters, but 囉 was not. The 1986 zong biao deletes 囉, and makes 啰 its official replacement "by analogy". Your dictionary seems to fall right in this period. Could be the entry you cite with 囉 was written before the 1986 list came out, and the entry with 啰 was done after. Or perhaps both were originally 囉 and in the editing they did after completing the dictionary, they missed the one entry.

Comment: It isn't just one entry though. I'll edit later. They seem to intentionally differentiate the two.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Hm, the last one is suggestive. 啰 *only* appears in the heading, and in the definition it is *always* 囉.  I still think the answer I gave above fits the case.  The book was prepared before the 1986 list came out, and used 囉 everywhere.  The list comes out, the editors go 'oy!', fix the headings, dust off their butts, and go home.

Comment: lazyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy uhhhhgghghghg

Comment: Hey I don't blame them.  Imagine you finish the report for your federal grant and they send it back to you with a letter saying that all official documents must now use British spelling.  I can think of a good non-verbal response for that one.

Comment: Find "o" -> Replace "ou" - I'm sure that would work out okay.... ;)